# shadow on image only, not entire width?

Tags: html, css

Her's the image of the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dobkx.jpg

Any recommendations on how to have just the image with the shadow and not the entire width?

I've tried a few different approaches but none are working... I'm doing something wrong obviously.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-2">
  <div class="image-circle-3">
      <div class="center-4">  
  <%= image_tag @listing.image_url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron-2 {
  background-color: grey; // height: 25vh;
  background-size: auto;
}

.image-circle-3 {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.center-4 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

The image is meant to be a circle but i took the CSS radius out just to test it and keep things simple.  In case you were wondering the name of the div :)

Comment: Put the shadow on the actual image, not the div?

Comment: Also, please use the editor image and upload to SO - some of us cannot see imgur due to policies on our domains.

Answer (score 1):

set the shadow to image instead of class  **.image-circle-3** as shown below:

```
.center-4 img{
   box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `box-shadow` style to `img` tag like below

CSS Code -

```
.image-circle-3 img {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Also, visit this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31Ljb4f8/4/) to show live